# Cloning Repo from Azure DevOps to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to clone the repo from Azure DevOps using SSH into Visual Studio 2022. I am trying to get the files that are on my repo and cloning into another computer but unable to get the files so that I can start work. I do not know what I am missing. I have the files and the html index file in the Azure DevOps Repo section in the browser and also the commits that I have made to the repo, but now I am unable to get the files from the repo to Visual Studio. The development branch is the one I am trying to get to reflect in Visual Studio 2022, using SSH to get clone the repo.

Fetching from Azure DevOps

[image]

Azure DevOps portal where the repo is

[image]

Branch not retrieve and reflecting

[image]

I did the following tasks:

- Created an SSH for the repo
- Added the SSH public key to the repo
- Provided a Pass phrase
- Copied the SSH URL to clone the repo
- Opened Visual Studio 2022 and cloned the repo
- The repo got cloned
- Branch not showing
- Files are missing

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the branch from the UI instead of using the git command in the Developer PowerShell.

Right click the branch name (development) you want to check out and choose **Checkout**.

[image]

Then you will find the files you need in the branch.

[image]